# Getting most recent item even if null from

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have three different tables, and im trying to get the output based on the different tables values below, but right now its returning all of the fields of table ranks, when i only want the latest one. the output should look like this:

`desire output:
╔════╦════════╦═══════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ id ║  value ║ name  ║ sum(total) ║ version ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ hola   ║ peter ║         52 ║ second  ║
║  2 ║ hello  ║ john  ║         16 ║ third   ║
║  3 ║ privet ║ luke  ║          3 ║ first   ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╩════════════╩═════════╝`

`table users
╔════╦════════╦═══════╦══╗
║ id ║ value  ║ name  ║  ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╬══╣
║  1 ║ hola   ║ peter ║  ║
║  2 ║ hello  ║ john  ║  ║
║  3 ║ privet ║ luke  ║  ║
║  4 ║ yay    ║ eli   ║  ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╩══╝`

`table props
╔════╦════════╦═════════╦══╗
║ id ║ value  ║ amount  ║  ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════╬══╣
║  1 ║ hola   ║      40 ║  ║
║  2 ║ hello  ║       5 ║  ║
║  3 ║ privet ║       3 ║  ║
║  4 ║ hello  ║       2 ║  ║
║  5 ║ hello  ║       9 ║  ║
║  6 ║ hola   ║      12 ║  ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════╩══╝`


`table ranks
╔════╦════════╦═════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║  value ║ version ║    date    ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ hola   ║ first   ║ 06-20-2015 ║
║  2 ║ hello  ║ first   ║ 04-24-2015 ║
║  3 ║ privet ║ first   ║ 02-01-2015 ║
║  4 ║ hello  ║ second  ║ 10-05-2015 ║
║  5 ║ hello  ║ third   ║ 01-03-2016 ║
║  6 ║ hola   ║ second  ║ 01-23-2016 ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════╩════════════╝`

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.value,
  users.name,
  sum(props.amount),
  ranks.version

FROM
  users
join props
on (users.value=props.value)
left join
on (users.value = ranks.value)


group by
  users.id,
  users.values,
  users.title,
  ranks.version
```

`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't `group by` the version if you want only one row for it.  When using aggregation, `keep` is a useful method:

```
SELECT u.id, u.value, u.name,
       sum(p.amount),
       max(r.version) keep (dense_rank first order by r.version) as version,
       max(r.value) keep (dense_rank first order by r.version) as value
FROM users u join
     props p
     on u.value = p.value left join
     ranks r
     on u.value = r.value
GROUP BY u.id, u.values, u.title;
```

Comment: thanks!, will this also output the `version` even if it's `null`?

Comment: @Joseph . . . It should output the version in the first record based on the `order by`.  You might need to use `NULLS FIRST` you want the `NULL` values to be first.